# Can a coinbase transaction have a segwit output?

Tags: segregated-witness, coinbase-transaction, output, p2wpkh, p2wsh

And more generally speaking, are there any restrictions on the output of a coinbase transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other than the total value needing to be correct (no more than the block reward plus fees), the outputs of a coinbase transaction are completely unrestricted and act the same as any other transaction.